# How to remove keys-values from dictionary 1 which are not in dictionary 2 based on common keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two large dictionaries and both dictionaries have same keys, (name of images) and have different values.

1st dict named `train_descriptions` which looks like this:

```
{'15970.jpg': 'Turtle Check Men Navy Blue Shirt',
 '39386.jpg': 'Peter England Men Party Blue Jeans',
 '59263.jpg': 'Titan Women Silver Watch',
 ....
 ....
 '1855.jpg': 'Inkfruit Mens Chain Reaction T-shirt'}
```

and a 2nd dict named `train_features`

```
{'31973.jpg': array([[0.00125694, 0.        , 0.03409385, ..., 0.00434341, 0.00728011,
         0.01451511]], dtype=float32),
 '30778.jpg': array([[0.0174035 , 0.04345186, 0.00772929, ..., 0.02230316, 0.        ,
         0.03104496]], dtype=float32),
 ...,
 ...,

 '38246.jpg': array([[0.00403965, 0.03701203, 0.02616892, ..., 0.02296285, 0.00930257,
         0.04575242]], dtype=float32)}
```

The length of both dictionaries are as follows:

`len(train_descriptions)` is 44424 and `len(train_features)` is 44441

As you can see length of `train_description` dict is less than length of `train_features`. `train_features` dictionary has more keys-values than `train_descriptions`. How do I remove the keys from `train_features` dictionary which are not in `train_description`? To make their length same.

Comment: You can convert both to sets (which creates sets of the keys), apply an appropriate set operation and remove the found keys in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for loop`

```
feat = train_features.keys()
desc = train_description.keys()
common = list(i for i in feat if i not in decc)

for i in common: del train_features[i]
```

Edit: See below

Above code works. But we can do this more efficiently by not converting dict_keys to list as follows:

```
for i in train_features.keys() - train_description.keys(): del train_features[i]
```

When python dict_keys are subtracted then it gives  dict_keys of uncommon keys. First code was first converting into list which was neither efficient nor required.

Comment: I would rather use a list comprehension than `list()` constructor plus a generator expression. Also iterating over a dictionary is based on its keys, no need for `.keys()`. `.keys()` is only useful when you need set like operations.

Comment: You mean like this: `for i in train_features.keys() - train_description.keys(): del train_features[i]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `xor` to get the difference between the dictionaries

```
diff = train_features.keys() ^ train_descriptions.keys()
for k in diff:
    del train_features[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

just `pop()` if not exist in another `dict`.

```
for key in train_descriptions.keys():
    if key not in train_features.keys():
        train_features.pop(key)
```

Comment: There is no need of converting dict.keys() to list. If it’s just used for loop we can directly pass it.